# Targeting specific class inside table with ID using CSS - Changing ROW background

Tags: php, html, css, background-color

I have a table that looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive" id="commenttable">
    <thead>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Message</th>
        <th>Tech</th>
        <th>Emailed?</th>
        <th>Date/Time</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            foreach($commresult as $row)
            {
                if($row['commentPrivate'] == 'yes'){
                    echo "<tr class='private'>";
                }
                else{
                    echo "<tr>";
                }
                echo "<td>" . ucwords($row['commentType']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . ucwords($row['commentSubject']) . "</a></td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['commentMessage'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  ucwords($row['commentBy']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  ucwords($row['commentEmailComm']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['commentDate'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
```

What I'm trying to do is `if $row['commentPrivate'] == 'yes'` I want to change the background color of just that row to red.

I've tried just using `<tr bgcolor="#ff7f7f">` which didn't work.  So now I'm just trying to add the class 'private' to the row and target it using `CSS`, which I think I'm failing at miserably.

Here's the css:

```
.private {
background-color: #ff7f7f;
}
```

I've also tried:

```
#commenttable tbody .private {
background-color: #ff7f7f;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try this `#commenttable tbody tr .private { background-color: #ff7f7f; }`

Comment: that does not work.  I echoed the $row['commentPrivate'] result and it is indeed 'yes'

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors? Or may be the CSS is getting overridden by some other CSS?

Comment: I dont see any erros in the console.  The only other CSS I have is for padding on the table data, but that's about it.

Comment: bootstraps table-striped shouldn't be overriding it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.table-striped` class adds zebra-stripes to a table. So to override the same, you can put `!important` in your CSS like this:

```
.private {
  background-color: #ff7f7f !important;
 }
```

Here is a [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/trleZb78Gu)

`.table .table-striped` is more specific than `.private`. Hence the rules for `.table-striped` prevails.

[image]

So, you can use `!important` to override the same.
The `!important` value appended a CSS property value is an automatic win. It overrides even inline styles from the markup. The only way an !important value can be overridden is with another !important rule declared later in the CSS and with equal or great specificity value otherwise.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot for the explanation.  On a side note, it didn't work until I removed table-responsive and table-hover classes, then it worked like a charm.  Any idea why that may be?

Comment: It is working with these classes in the demo that I provided. So its is difficult to conclude, what could possibly create the issue.

Answer (score 3):

```
#commenttable .private {
  background-color: #ff7f7f !important;
}
```